# windows task scheduler send an e-mail with result

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I am trying to send an email from windows task scheduler with Action tab. But How can I include the Last run result in this mail. I am not getting any option along with it. There is an option of attaching the files to the mail. So if an one could help me is there any logs files generated by the task scheduler when a task is being run? if so where can I find the log    ?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to redirect the result into a log file.And then send that log as an attachment.
For send as email , there is definitely an attach button.